# How to create a function that will add new elements into an empty array(JS)?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to get some unit testing to work and I'm running into problems when writing a function that will add a new ingredient to my empty array.

The test says:

```
it("should be able to add ingredients to an array", function() {
      var ingredients = [];

      addIngredients("cheese", ingredients);

      assert.equal(ingredients.length, 1);
      assert.deepEqual(ingredients, ["cheese"]);
    });
```

My code is not working... it says that the array is still empty when it should return 1. Any advice on how to get this function to add to the empty array?

My code:

```
function addIngredients(ingredients) {
  var ingredients = [];
  ingredients.push();
  return ingredients;
}

addIngredients("cheese");
```

Still very green, any advice that can lead me in the right direction would be great!

Comment: You're not pushing anything into your array (is missing argument) and your first addIngredients had 2 arguments but it latter has one parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want your `addIngredients()` function to receive both the string and the array to which that string will be pushed as parameters. In this, case you can use the following code:

```js
var ingredients = [];

function addIngredients(ingredient, array) {
  array.push(ingredient);
  return array;
}

addIngredients("cheese", ingredients);

console.log(ingredients);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var ingredients = [];

function addIngredients(ingredient) {
  ingredients.push(ingredient);
  return ingredients;
}

addIngredients("cheese");
addIngredients("oil");

console.log(ingredients);
```

Answer (score -1):

Check if it's work.

```
     var ingredients = [];
     function addIngredients(ingredient) {
       ingredients.push(ingredient);
       return ingredients;
     }

     addIngredients("cheese");
```